# Video display issue in Adobe flex android mobile development?

Tags: android, apache-flex, flash-builder, youtube-api

I have two views, view1 and view2. Which is been developed by using Adobe Flex4.6

1) **View1**

View1 displayes video information, but it will not play videos.

2) **View2**

View2 display's only  video player, which is playing selected video from View1.

**Problem:**

When user moves from View1->View2, video is played. if user go back to  **View1**, Video which was playing in View2 is not destroyed.  Because of this, if user selects one more video in View1, both video starts to play together, when user moves to View2 again.

Please let me know, what is that I need to do to destroy data, when user moves back.

Thanks,

Comment: I don't fully understand your UI.  Are View1 and View2 two separate screens?  Or part of the same screen, like a SplitViewNavigator?  Can you provide code for View1 or View2?  How are you switching between views?  Perhaps you just need to execute some code in response to a viewDeactivate event? http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/View.html#event:viewDeactivate

Comment: View1 and View2 are separate screens. I am switching between screen by using PushView() method

Comment: If you are using youtube videos then probably this is due to youtube uses older version of Actionscript. older versions of Actionscript doesn't go nice with newer versions. The same problem happens with desktop applications. Try different video sharing site or check with some local videos.

Answer (score 1):

You can listen to 
`FlexEvent.VIEW_DEACTIVATE`
 (Dispatched when the current view has been deactivated)
and 
`FlexEvent.REMOVING`
( Dispatched when the screen is about to be removed in response to a screen change) events to clear your data, as flex does not force your views to be destroyed immediately.

Consider reading http://corlan.org/2011/01/12/understanding-flex-mobile-views-and-viewnavigator for better views understanding.